# Event press to get JSON object SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, json, sapui5

I am new with SAPUI5, but I have a problem with event press function in SAPUI5. in API documents, not clear for me. I want to get object JSON when I press menu (dropdown menu).

JS:

```
MessageToast.show(oEvent.getSource().getBindingContext().getProperty("name"));
```

but I not understand with this code and use for "getSource()" or etc. Where I find the document for explain this problem? I have difficulty with event in SAPUI5. Thanks.

JSON:

```
dropdownMenu: {
  kepesertaan:[
    {
      name: "Menu1",
      icon: "sap-icon://crop",
      sub: [
        {
          name: "Submenu1-1",
          icon: "sap-icon://create-session"
        },
        {
          name: "Submenu1-2",
          icon: "sap-icon://create-form"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: "Menu2",
      icon: "sap-icon://detail-view",
      sub: [
        {
          name: "Submenu2-1",
          icon: "sap-icon://add-activity"
        },
        {
          name: "Submenu2-2",
          icon: "sap-icon://action"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: "Menu3",
      icon: "sap-icon://delete",
      sub: [
        {
          name: "Submenu3-1",
          icon: "sap-icon://add-favorite"
        },
        {
          name: "Submenu3-2",
          icon: "sap-icon://add-document"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: sap.ui.unified.Menu

Answer (score 0):

UI5's eventing relies on jQuery events. You can have a look at the [Event Object](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.base.Event.html) documentation.

Simply - once an interaction is done an event is triggered. So the attached callback is invoked which has this oEvent parameter. The oEvent contains all the needed information for the event (E.g. which control throws the event - in your case it is the Menu). Also most of the events have parameters which define what and where it happens.

[Unified menu documentation](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.unified.Menu.html)
[Mobile menu documentation](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.Menu.html)

Notice that both have an event that has an information if [an item is selected](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.unified.Menu.html#event:itemSelect).

I would recommend you to try the [Walkthrough](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/entity/sap.m.tutorial.walkthrough/samples)